# How to get a list of friends the user invited in a Facebook app?

Tags: facebook

When users invite friends to my Facebook application with e.g. fb:multi-friend-selector, how can the application get a list of friends (uids) the user just invited? My application has internal "groups" and I need to connect the invites to these groups and therefore have this possibility.

We all know Facebook's documentation isn't very verbose and I've spent some considerable time researching this to no avail yet. Creative ideas to solve my problem are also appreciated.

Comment: Actually the multi-friend-selector provides the selected users in a call-back url.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Kyberias is correct, however a bit more information is good.

One of the attributes for `<fb:request-form>` (which must surround the `<fb:multi-friend-request>`) is `action`.  This is the URL where the form will POST the data, and in that request will be an array of invited user ids, named 'ids'.

http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/fbml/request-form

Answer (score 0):

Actually the multi-friend-selector provides the selected users in a call-back url.